# Asserting one object with a mock object using mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to test creation of a elasticsearch client object with a mock object.

The interface looks like the below

```
public interface DBClient<T> {
    public T getClient() throws Exception;
}
```

The implementation looks like below

```
public class ElasticSearchClient implements DBClient<RestClient> {

    private String _hostName, _scheme;
    private int _port;

    public ElasticSearchClient(String hostname, int port, String scheme) {
        this._hostName = hostname;
        this._port = port;
        this._scheme = scheme;
    }

    public RestClient getClient() throws Exception {

        return RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(_hostName, _port, _scheme)).build();

    }
}
```

I am writing a test case to check if I am getting a valid object

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DBClientTest {

    private final String hostname = "search-sdsessec-us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com";
    private final int port = 443;
    private final String scheme = "https";

    @Mock
    public DBClient<RestClient> dbClientMock;

    @Test
    public void testGetClientReturnsElasticSearchClient() throws Exception {
        ElasticSearchClient esClient = new ElasticSearchClient(hostname, port, scheme);
        Assert.assertEquals(esClient.getClient(), when(dbClientMock.getClient()).thenReturn(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(hostname, port, scheme)).build()));
    }

}
```

Is this the right way to test. Please help.

Comment: *"Is this the right way to test."* - No. In tests you mock *dependencies*, not your *code under test* Your `ElasticSearchClient` (which is your *code under test*) **is a** `DBClient<RestClient>` so is does not make sense to create a mock of the latter...

Comment: ok now i got it. So how do i test or change the above code. Could you please help me

Comment: or should i just not do this case at all.

Comment: Additionall, what is RestClient ? A custom class ? A third party class ? Is it an expensive operation to create it with `RestClient.builder`? You have to mock dependencies only as it makes sense

Comment: In my world a class called `ElasticSearchClient` should not have a method called `getClient()`. This is like beeing able to get a car out of another car. So get the *separation of concerns/Single Responsibility* patterns clear first.

Comment: @davidxxx The RestClient is a third party class

Comment: @TimothyTruckle sure, I will work on that